# Best practice to define image storage location

Tags: php, git, laravel

I'm building an eCommerce app in Laravel and it requires to save images from various pages like Add product, Add request, Update profile etc. I've defined the image storage location right on the controller files itself for the respective items.

```
UserController.php    
$targetPath = '/Users/apple/Documents/eCommApp/storage/app/public/uploads/' . $user . '/img/profile/';

ProductController.php 
$targetPath = '/Users/apple/Documents/eCommApp/storage/app/public/uploads/' . $user . '/img/product/';
```

My problem is I need to keep updating the image storage location on remote server everytime new codes are committed through git since its different in local and remote servers.

My question is:

1. Can we create a constants.php inside config/ and then define all paths there only and then include this file in .gitignore so that this file is ignored while pushing the code?
2. Is it the best (secure, efficient) way to deal with image storage location in Laravel?

Looking for yours advices,

Thank you

PS: Here is the code to save gig image.

```
if ($request->hasFile('ref_img')) {
        if($request->file('ref_img')->isValid()) {
            $types = array('_original.', '_150.', '_128.', '_64.', '_32.');
            $sizes = array('150', '128', '64', '32');

            $targetPath = '/Users/apple/Documents/eCommApp/storage/app/public/uploads/' . $user . '/img/gig/';

            try {
                $file = $request->file('ref_img');
                $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                if ($gig->img == NULL){
                    $fName = time();
                } else {
                    $fName = basename($gig->img, ".".$ext);
                }

                $o_name = $fName . array_shift($types) . $ext;
                $original = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
                $original->save($targetPath . $o_name);
                foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
                    $newName = $fName . $type . $ext;
                    $newImg = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
                    $newImg->resize($sizes[$key], null, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });
                    $newImg->save($targetPath . $newName);
                }
                $gig->img = 'storage/uploads/' . $user . '/img/gig/' . $fName . '.' . $ext;
            } catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for environment variables, read the `config` documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration

Comment: @sam but why you want to keep and care about an additional variable if you just can use `public_path()` which will generate the correct path on any system?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I was responding to his question about storing configuration values that are not included in version control. I know that in this situation it's not appropriate, but it's an important concept he isn't aware of so making him aware will help with any future situation he encounters where there needs to be differing configuration values per environment -- which is very common. The main question had already been answered when I made my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#available-methods) like [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-public-path):

```
$targetPath = public_path($user . '/img/profile/');
```

This helper will generate a full path to `public` directory in your Laravel project.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Image::make method while storing images and I need to use getRealPath() to get the absolute path. Public_path is not working in that scenario. Hence, I've been using the absolute path instead.

Comment: @chuck you need `getRealPath()` only to read saved image. Then you should copy it (maybe rename too) and store just a name of the file in DB. Later you'll be able to build full path with `public_path()` and stored image filename.